# Modifying site to be more mobile friendly

Tags: html, responsive-design

quick question. Is there a way to sort of jury rig an old site built with tables instead of divs to be more mobile friendly? At my job we are wondering if there is a way to get something working really fast while we spend a bit more time redesigning our sites.

Comment: Have you looked at adding a library such as Bootstrap? There are classes included such as `table-responsive` which might help you (I use them).

Comment: Bootstrap is a framework, not a library ;)

Comment: Good point @LelioFaieta ! I'm not great with the terminology sorry...

Comment: This website is on 3dCart if that helps at all.